# Display icon in TextField when not empty

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to do simple thing.. Displaying clear button when the TextField is not empty to clear the content and hide it when content is empty. Here is code

```
   final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
       ...

                   TextFormField(
                      controller: _controller,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          suffixIcon: _controller.text.length > 0
                              ? IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.clear, size: 16),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    _controller.clear();
                                  },
                                )
                              : null))
```

This works but not with the keyboard activated. You have to close the keyboard to make it work.. How to do it live while typing with controller?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to update the state every time the input changes:

```
TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  _controller.addListener(() {
    setState(() {});
  });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: _controller,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          suffixIcon: _controller.text.isNotEmpty
              ? IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.clear, size: 16),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _controller.clear();
                  },
                )
              : null,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks friend! You are the best 

Answer (score 2):

Its because your UI is not rebuild until you close your keyboard which will trigger the rebuild, for this, you can use this little trick like this:

````
  final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

  changesOnField() {
    setState(() {}); // Will re-Trigger Build Method
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller.addListener(changesOnField);
  }```
````