# How can I show checkmark icon on text field when I ended up with writing

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Here is my Textfield Widget:

```
Widget textfields(String hint, TextEditingController cont) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
      child: TextField(
        
        controller: cont,
        autofocus: false,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.orange),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Colors.blueGrey[50],
          hintText: hint,
          contentPadding:
              const EdgeInsets.only(left: 14.0, bottom: 12.0, top: 10.0),
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.7),
          ),
          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.7),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[Click here to see the example what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6phJ.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62433982/display-icon-in-textfield-when-not-empty

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display icon in TextField when not empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62433982/display-icon-in-textfield-when-not-empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case we need `FocusNode` and have to listen to it.

To handle `suffixIcon` we will use `Visibility` with  `visible: !focusNode.hasFocus && controller.text.isNotEmpty,` you can change condition the way like.

**Result**

[image]

**Full Code**

```
class Body extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BodyState createState() => _BodyState();
}

class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
  final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

  final TextEditingController controller2 = TextEditingController();

  final FocusNode focusNode1 = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode focusNode2 = FocusNode();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    focusNode1.addListener(() {
      print(focusNode1.hasFocus.toString());
      setState(() {});
    });

    focusNode2.addListener(() {
      print(focusNode2.hasFocus.toString());
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    focusNode1.removeListener(() {});
    focusNode2.removeListener(() {});
    focusNode1.dispose();
    focusNode2.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Column(
      children: [
        textfields("start typing", controller, focusNode1),
        textfields("start 2", controller2, focusNode2),
        ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
            },
            child: Text("B"))
      ],
    ));
  }

  Widget textfields(
    String hint,
    TextEditingController cont,
    FocusNode focusNode,
  ) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
      child: TextField(
        controller: cont,
        autofocus: false,
        focusNode: focusNode,
        onSubmitted: (value) {
          print("submitted");
        },
        onEditingComplete: () {
          print("dome com");
        },
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.orange),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          suffixIcon: Visibility(
            visible: !focusNode.hasFocus && controller.text.isNotEmpty,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.check_circle,
              color: Colors.blueGrey,
            ),
          ),
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Colors.blueGrey[50],
          hintText: hint,
          contentPadding:
              const EdgeInsets.only(left: 14.0, bottom: 12.0, top: 10.0),
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.7),
          ),
          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.7),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```